# Impossible to put my $_GET variable in SQL statement

Tags: php, html

I try to make SQL statement with a $_GET variable

This is my handler.php:

```php
if(array_key_exists("task", $_GET)){
  $task = $_GET['task'];
}

if(array_key_exists("id", $_GET)){
  $id_event = $_GET['id'];
}

if($task == "write"){
  postMessage();
} else {
  getMessages();
}

function getMessages(){
  global $pdo;
  global $id_event;

  $resultats = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id_messages_evenement = :id ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10");

  $resultats->execute([
      "id" => $id_event
  ]);

  $messages = $resultats->fetchAll();
  echo json_encode($messages);
}
```

And my form :

```php
        <form action="../src/App/handler.php?task=write&id=13" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name ="auteur" id="auteur" value="<?php echo $id_membre ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name ="id_event" id="id_event" value="<?php echo $id_event ?>">
            <input type="text" id="message" name="message">
            <button type="submit">Envoyer</button>
        </form>
```

but the SQL statement doesn't work.

If I try `$id_event = 13;` instead of

```
if(array_key_exists("id", $_GET)){
  $id_event = $_GET['id'];
}
```

the statement is working, so y think my problem come from $_GET['id'].

Everytime someone post a message with the form, this is call "../src/App/handler.php?task=write&id=[...]" with id=13 for example, So I want to do 
`SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id_messages_evenement = 13 ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10`

EDIT: this is my chat.js for using AJAX:

```
function getMessages(){
    const requeteAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requeteAjax.open("GET", "../src/App/handler.php");

    requeteAjax.onload = function(){
      const resultat = JSON.parse(requeteAjax.responseText);
      console.log(resultat);
      const html = resultat.reverse().map(function(mess){
        return `
          <div class="message">
            <span class="date">${mess.date.substring(11, 16)}</span>
            <span class="author">${mess.id_auteur}</span> : 
            <span class="content">${mess.message}</span>
          </div>
        `;
      }).join('');

      const messages = document.querySelector('.messages');

      messages.innerHTML = html;
      messages.scrollTop = messages.scrollHeight;
    }
    requeteAjax.send();
  }

  function postMessage(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const auteur = document.querySelector('#auteur');
    const id_event = document.querySelector('#id_event');
    const message = document.querySelector('#message');

    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('message', message.value);
    data.append('auteur', auteur.value);
    data.append('id_event', id_event.value);

    const requeteAjax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    requeteAjax.open('POST', '../src/App/handler.php?task=write');

    requeteAjax.onload = function(){
      content.value = '';
      content.focus();
      getMessages();
    }
    requeteAjax.send(data);
  }

  document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', postMessage);
  const interval = window.setInterval(getMessages, 1000);
  getMessages();
```

Comment: What are the contents of `$_GET`?

Comment: check `print_r($_GET);` on top and see that value is coming or not? show us that value

Comment: what if `id` is NOT set in $_GET variables? Tnen your query will fail, since you execute it anyway without checking if id is indeed given

Comment: I will edit my post to show the URL

Comment: If the task=write then it means you will call `postMessage()` instead of `getMessages()`

Comment: @Dharman no if =write, I want to post a new message

Comment: Hey samuel try to get the id with $_POST because in the method postMessage you are sending a post request with ajax, so the id will never get passed there via $_GET.

Comment: Thank Diar, but when I try to do ```function getMessage(){$id_event = $_POST['id_event'];}```, in this is not working.

Comment: @samuel  why php function have jquery code in it?

Comment: Also you need to add the id somehow in the url that you are calling in the getMessage() 
```requeteAjax.open("GET", "../src/App/handler.php?id={id}");```